# Undefined property: App\Events\UserWalletNewTransaction::$user_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-events

I have created an Event called `UserWalletNewTransaction.php` and added this to it:

```
public $transaction;

public function __construct($transaction) {
    $this->$transaction = $transaction;
}
```

And also registered it at `EventServiceProivder.php`:

```
use App\Listeners\UserWalletNotification;

protected $listen = [
    UserWalletNewTransaction::class => [
        UserWalletNotification::class,
    ],
```

Now in order to fire this event at the Controller, I coded this:

```
$newTransaction = UserWalletTransaction::create(['user_id' => $user_id, 'wallet_id' => $wallet_id, 'creator_id' => $creator_id, 'amount' => $amount_add_value, 'description' => $trans_desc]);

event(new UserWalletNewTransaction($newTransaction));
```

Then at the listener, `UserWalletNotification.php`, I tried:

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->user_id;
    dd($uid);
}
```

But I get `Undefined property: App\Events\UserWalletNewTransaction::$user_id` error message.

However, if I try `dd($event)`, this result successfully come up:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? How can I get the `user_id` that already exists at `$event`?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, you are trying to access `$user_id` on an object that is `App\Events\UserWalletNewTransaction` and not your `UserWalletTransaction` model.

Your fix is:

```php
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->transaction->user_id;
}
```

---

If you use a good IDE, this would never happen to you, as it would already tell you that `$event` is `UserWalletNewTransaction`. Try using another IDE or one that can autocomplete that, so you can develop faster and better.

Comment: `Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object`

Comment: @loctoj then, you did not create the object... `UserWalletTransaction::create` did not return an object, maybe it was not added, I think it returned `false` or `null`, as your original image shows... this is basic debugging, do `dd($event->transaction)` and show us the result.

Comment: If the answer is `null`, then it is not creating the object, I think you may have not defined something in the model as `$fillable` property. Check that or create a new question as our code is correct, but you have a new problem now. I still have to say that you have some data in your image, I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

Try following, add this in your Event class `UserWalletNewTransaction`

```
public $transaction;
public function __construct(UserWalletTransaction $transaction)
{
    $this->transaction = $transaction;
}
```

and in Listener

```
public function handle(UserWalletNewTransaction $event) {
    $uid = $event->transaction->user_id;
    dd($uid);
}
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Events\UserWalletNewTransaction::__construct() must be an instance of App\Events\UserWalletTransaction, instance of App\UserWalletTransaction given, called in UserWalletController.php

Comment: You have to add at the beginning of your event class this code `use App\UserWalletTransaction;`.